# Configure Behat for using Appium

Tags: php, bdd, behat, appium

For a project, I try to configure Behat to work with Appium (for mobile testing).

But after configuring the `behat.yml` file to connect to Appium (the protocol used is the same as Selenium), I have an error that Behat cannot connect to the server.

Does somebody have ever configure Behat to work with Appium ?
Can you help me ?

Comment: Can you paste the error and the desired_capabilities you're trying to start Appium with?

Comment: I've got this error: _Curl error thrown for http POST to http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub/session with params: {"desiredCapabilities":{"browserName":"safari","version":"8","platform":"ANY","browserVersion":"8","browser":"firefox","name":"Behat test","deviceOrientation":"portrait","deviceType":"tablet","selenium-version":"2.31.0","max-duration":300},"requiredCapabilities":[]}
  couldn't connect to host`_ But the Appium desktop is started with this info : _info: Appium REST http interface listener started on 0.0.0.0:4723_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the URL when you create the webdriver in your script to `0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub` it's currently set to `127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub/`

But once you fix that, you'll have another issue because your `desiredCapabilities` are also wrong. You're trying to add two browsers below? I don't understand what you're trying to do there.

> `"browserName":"safari","version":"8","platform":"ANY","b‌​rowserVersion":"8","browser":"firefox","`

Please check the **[Appium documentation](http://appium.io/slate/en/master/?ruby#toc_52)** for how to fix them.

Comment: My problem is not about the desiredCapabilities, but realy why Behat cannot connect to Appium. The both are running on the same machine. I'm going to try to change _127.0.0.1_ to _0.0.0.0_ tomorrow... but without conviction

Comment: For me 127.0.0.1 and 0.0.0.0 which work as the same in this case

Comment: OH.. I see... I mean `couldn't connect to host` means it can't reach Appium for whatever reason